# Cannot get rid of nvidia drivers, restore nouveau driver and get desktop working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I made the mistake of installing the Nvidia Linux drivers direct from their website.
It failed because it could not remove the nouveau driver.

Next I manually installed the nvidia drivers from the repository which successfully installed the nvidia driver, but the Ubuntu desktop does not function; no launcher, no menu bar, no windows. (Gnome seems to work though).

So I want to revert back to the vanilla installed nouveau driver.
I tried

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo reboot
```

but lshw -c video reveals I still have one nvidia driver  and one i915 driver.
nouveau has not returned and the desktop will not function.

I am considering a complete reinstall, is there anything else to try?

I have followed the other threads with the same issues, but the solutions did not work

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Creates an error.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg.core libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Did not make a difference.

```
cccm
```

Same.

Comment: For me, substituting in a xorg.conf file worked, even using the failsafe one already in the folder. If there's absolutely no xorg.conf, it'll likely not work.

Answer (score 14):

Had the same problem.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx
```

This actually fixed it. Ubuntu 13.10 x64 + nVidia 740M. Thank you very much!

You did not mention your GPU. If you've had that problem on a laptop, I'd suggest its because of the so-called "Fusion" system (which uses your integrated GPU in lieu of discrete one when you don't need it).

Comment: This should be xserver-xorg-core I guess.

Comment: Do not recommend to run it on 16.04. Just killed all xserver for me

Answer (score 11):

Ultimate fix:

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
sudo reboot now
```

Do not remove xorg.conf file, I repeat do not remove xorg.conf.

Comment: Why not to remove xorg.conf ? If there is some nvidia-specific stuff inside, I quess it could bring X to dont work any more. I just moved it to xorg.conf.backup and did the reboot --> worked like a charm, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 8):

Be sure you remove all blacklist entries involving nouveau from `/etc/modprobe.d` as well.

Otherwise even if the system is configured to use it, it will not. I believe `blacklist-local`, and the `nvidia backlists` will be of primary concern.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Mine turned out to be a badly configured `bumblebee.conf` referencing `nvidia-304` in one place and `nvidia-current` in another.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cd /etc/modules-load.d/ 
mv nvidia.conf nvidia.conf.backup

cd /etc/modprobe.d/
mv nvidia-blacklists-nouveau.conf nvidia-blacklists-nouveau.conf.backup
mv nvidia.conf nvidia.conf.backup
mv nvidia-kernel-common.conf nvidia-kernel-common.conf.backup
```

Good luck!