# [Help]Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu gnome 16.04 not w

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, gnome, msi

I really don't know what to do now.. I tried for a month all the different methods to install nvidia drivers (bumblebee, primus, via nvidia website, via Ubuntu drivers..) red, red and red ! But still not working. 
I'm having a MSI GS60 6QC and a GTX 960m card.. can someone help me ? :)
Btw even if it doesn't work I learnt so much !

Comment: For MSI GS60 6QC Ubuntu 16.10 may give better results (and has a newer Nvidia driver version directly available in its repository). That said, please edit you question and describe "not working"...

Comment: @CelticWarrior I will try

Answer (score 0):

[These steps](http://www.castoriscausa.com/posts/ge62vr-mint-gtx1060) worked for me in Mint18, they might apply for you.

1. [Return to Nouveau drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360761/cannot-get-rid-of-nvidia-drivers-restore-nouveau-driver-and-get-desktop-working)
2. Purge any NVIDIA software
3. Install NVIDIA binaries for Ubuntu