# After uninstalling nvidia drivers Xorg does not start

Tags: xorg, 17.10, plasma, sddm

After uninstalling nvidia drivers and existing (`sudo killall Xorg`) Xorg does not start any more.

Running `sddm &` simply gives this in output and exits:

```
Aborted
```

If running Xorg manually I see this error in log:

```
vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/360761/cannot-get-rid-of-nvidia-drivers-restore-nouveau-driver-and-get-desktop-working

Answer (score 0):

It looks like NVIDIA does not handle uninstall properly, it leaves its kernel modules enabled:

```
# lsmod |grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm             45056  0
nvidia              10584064  1 nvidia_uvm
drm                   483328  5 nvidia,nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_core               94208  6 i2c_algo_bit,nvidia,nouveau,psmouse,drm_kms_helper,drm
```

Run this to disable them:

```
rmmod nvidia_uvm
rmmod nvidia
```

Enable `nouveau` driver (which is also not done by nvidia drivers uninstaller):

```
modprobe nouveau
```

Now can run `sddm &`

---

Alternatively, you could have restarted the system, but hey, it's not macos.