# How to fix : could not load "image-loading"

Tags: ubuntu-mate, openbox

I'm using ubuntu Mate 18.04 with the window manager Openbox, when I try to change the wallpaper using Nitrogen I receive this error :

`ERR: Could not load "image-loading" from icon theme, this indicates a problem with your Gtk/Gtkmm install.`

How can I fix it, I researched, but the questions I found did not help me

Comment: Do you happen to have an nvidia card with the `novaeu` driver?

Comment: I don't have a nvidia, how can I check if I have this drive, I mean what's the name of the package (I used dpkg -l novaeu and apt -q list | grep novaeu to see, but I coudn't find nothing)

Comment: `novaeu` is a nvidia only driver so if you don't have a nvidia card, it's unlikely that you will have it installed. add the output of `lspci | grep VGA` to your question

Comment: Am I install [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360761/cannot-get-rid-of-nvidia-drivers-restore-nouveau-driver-and-get-desktop-working) way. The output 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)